# How to parse in KQL

Tags: parsing, extract, kql

need to parse this information in KQL

```
{"firmware_manufacturer":"Cisco","firmware_device_type":["Switch"],"firmware_model":"WS-C2960CX-8PC-L","firmware_original_versions":[{"hardware_version":null,"software_version":"15.2(7)E"}
```

Expected output is like below

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| firmware_manufacturer | Cisco |
| firmware_device_type | Swtich |
| firmware_model | WS-C2960CX-8PC-L |
| Software_version | 15.2(7)E" |

We can rename the first column as well

I tried to parse through KQL extract function. But unable to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `parse_json` function for parsing a `string` value into a `dynamic` value.

you'd be better off modifying your schema to have the column typed as `dynamic` to begin with, so that you don't need to perform this parsing at query time

- [The `dynamic` datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic)
- [`parse_json()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parse-json-function)

```
print payload_str = '{"firmware_manufacturer":"Cisco","firmware_device_type":["Switch"],"firmware_model":"WS-C2960CX-8PC-L","firmware_original_versions":[{"hardware_version":null,"software_version":"15.2(7)E"}]}'
| project payload = parse_json(payload_str)
| project
    firmware_manufacturer = payload.firmware_manufacturer,
    firmware_device_type = payload.firmware_device_type[0],
    firmware_model = payload.firmware_model,
    software_version = payload.firmware_original_versions[0].software_version
```

| firmware_manufacturer | firmware_device_type | firmware_model | software_version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cisco | Switch | WS-C2960CX-8PC-L | 15.2(7)E |

Comment: Thanks Yoni L. Let you know for more information!